# Linq match value from 2 tables

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables, and I just wanna select the "Active" value only. PeriodID for Table1  is fixed with D1,D2,D3, and D4 only. It won't increase anymore. The active status might change.

My table 1 as follow:

```
PeriodID | Active
------------------
   D1    |    Y
   D2    |    Y
   D3    |    N
   D4    |    Y
```

My table 2 as follow:

```
RateID | CompanyCode |  D1  |  D2  |  D3  | D4
------------------------------------------------
  1    |    C1       |  1.1 |  1.5 |  1.9 | 2.0
  2    |    C2       |  2.1 |  2.5 |  2.9 | 3.0
```

How do I achievement expected result as below? Thanks

```
RateID | CompanyCode |  D1  |  D2  | D4
----------------------------------------
  1    |      C1     |  1.1 |  1.5 | 2.0
  2    |      C2     |  2.1 |  2.5 | 3.0
```

Below is my query without filter:

```
From c In DB.Table2 Select c.D1,c.D2,c.D3,c.D4
```

Comment: This is an example of a query that has no fixed result shape, the number of columns to return depends on the data in the database. Linq is not very good at that. I'm not saying it can't be done, but it won't be intuitive and you'll need at least two queries, one after the other.

Comment: PeriodId should be ForeignKey in Rate instead of having columns of same name.

Comment: if PeriodId is ForeignKey, how do I check active or inactive for the rate?-@ethicallogics

Comment: This is home work for all :)

Comment: Do you know how to do that? How about if using SQL?-@Kris Vandermotten

Comment: I agree with Kris VanderMotten. In addition, how would you manage the difference in columns in code? I wouldn't worry to much about that extra column and just check in code whether you need to show the column. Another option is when you do not need change tracking to use `db.ExecuteStoreQuery<MyEntity>(/*MyQueryString build dynamically in code*/);`